# Глобальный фильтр по полю, которого нету в сущности

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Можно ли в EF сконфигурировать сущность так, чтобы применить глобальный фильтр по полю, которого нету в модели?

Допустим, у меня для каких-то целей есть ненормализованная сущность и я хочу туда замапить несколько моделей и в каждом маппинге модели прописать глобальный фильтр, которого нет среди полей.

Comment: При желании, [можно всякого напридумывать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35631903/12888024), а зачем?

Comment: Ну... Например, у меня ненормализованная таблица для каких-то своих нужд и я хотел бы смапить на нее несколько моделей, но что бы все было четко, нужно в конфигурации повесить фильтрацию по полю, которое я не хочу добавлять в эти модели.

Comment: Сценарий интересный, но не типичный, с ходу не скажу точно, но почти уверен, что проще все-таки добавить поле. Ну или сделать единую модель для таблички, а дочерние модели пусть вырастают не из таблички, а из главной модели. То есть главная модель будет иметь нужное поле и уметь правильно выфильтровывать данные.

Comment: Если прятать за репозиторием эту общую сущность, а наружу выставляя маленькие модельки, то проблематично на вход принимать фильтрующий Expression, так как его придется перестраивать внутри делая из него "большую" сущность.

Comment: Ну это уже тонкости и нюансы реализации. Не всегда можно сделать "красиво", иногда приходится ради удобства или просто благой цели втыкать костыли. Но когда это оправдано, и код при этом не перестает быть поддерживаемым/масштабируемым - то почему нет?

Answer (score 0):

Использованию shadow properties посвящен [раздел документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

Настроить глобальный фильтр можно в методе `OnModelCreating` используя `HasQueryFilter`.
В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/filters) даже есть пример глобального фильтра на такое свойство:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "_tenantId") == _tenantId);
```